# How to Query Solr ? and modify Schema.xml

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using **Apache Solr**   contains documents like below mentioned Doc examples:

Doc 1:( Tags: head pain,name: B)
Doc 2:( Tags : chest pain,name: A)
Doc 3:(Tags: leg pain,name: C)

When i Query "`leg pain`" .. I'm getting all documents in response.

How to get Exact match i.e., only 'leg pain' matching document.
As of now I'm using field Type as :String

Do i need to make any changes in schema file?

Comment: can you post you solr  query

Comment: Exactly what is the type of the field? If it's a _string_ field, only exact matches will be returned. What does your query look like? Are you using wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

That is because default operator(OR) when you search `leg pain` Solr search for `leg` and also `pain` as different words. document having both words will be top in the results.

For exact match, use PhraseQuery. use double quotes `"leg pain"` in this case solr search for document having entire phrase `leg pain`.

Comment: Thanks This i knew ..Is there any other solution. but when i search for only   "pain" i will not get any document in response

Comment: check in solr admin analysis page. also check for stopword filter.

Comment: I have added words in stopwords.txt  as : #I # have #the ...but its not filtering out stop words given in stopwords.txt what to do? can please provide stopword file

Comment: Dont use `#` its used to comment. just specify one word `an the it` in each line

Comment: check schema file for field definition. Is `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" />` added in schema file.? if possible post fieldType definition for field name Tags

Answer (score 0):

For **exact match** you can set mm(Minimum "Should" Match) parameter of your query parser to 100% in your solrconfig.xml
This specifies a minimum number of clauses that must match in a query.
Or you can override this parameter (q.mm) at query-time in request

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a different relevance mechanism boosting the content by proximity. Using eDismax, you're looking for **pf** and **ps** parameters as explained in the relevance Solr [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser). For instance if you are querying a field called tags, your query would look like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<YOUR_COLLECTION>/select?defType=edismax&q=head pain&pf=tags&ps=10
```

that will return results as required in your comments.
In particular ps (Phrase Slop) parameter:

> Sets the number of other words permitted between words in query
>   phrase. If zero, then this is an exact phrase search. For larger
>   values this works like a WITHIN or NEAR operator. The slop is in fact
>   an edit-distance, where the units correspond to moves of terms in the
>   query phrase out of position.

Comment: I dnt want to boost anything . and how dismax and edismax works.

Comment: @Naveens eDismax is an extended parser that provides a wider set of query options. If you have a choice, you'd prefer to use eDismax over the DefaultQueryParser that you're probably using. Even if you don't want to boost anything, proximity is a relevance mechanism commonly used in order to achieve what you're looking for and the solution proposed will work. Try the query provided and you'll see that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SOLR verison 3`, you can try the following field type

```
    <fieldType name="input_general" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And change term field to be:

```
<field name="Tags" type="input_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

So, you would remove the spaces from the input itself and it will return exactly what you need:

`Exact Match Search`; you can try q=Tags:"legpain"

Comment: There is no need to paste this answer into multiple questions, as it's actually removing accuracy from an exact hit.

Comment: It's not a copy/paste answer, it's the same answer needed for his scenario.